# Issue with UIButton Title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am fetching the data from UITableViewCell and am storing into string is countryString. I want to change the button title with country string but its not working, i thought it is a simple issue, but am struggling from last 2 hours. still I cant find the solution why is not working

```
    countryButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(145, 145, 100, 30)];
    countryButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    [countryButton setTitle:CountryString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    countryButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [countryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(countryTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [notesView addSubview:countryButton]; 


-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{   
    jsonDict = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CountryString=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"countryName"];
    NSLog(@"country is %@", CountryString);
    CountryTableview.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: u were mention the button type

Comment: the code in this method gets called? if not try putting it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method and try

Comment: You need to refresh that row/column in the tableview I guess, so that the cell will be re-populated with the updated `CountryString`.  Why did you assume that would happen automatically?

Comment: where u want to show the button in tableview or else where

Comment: You may need to set the font attributes too for this to work -     countryButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

Comment: what i just need set the button title with string i think here no need  to update the cell @trojanfoe

Comment: And the normal way of doing that is to tell the tableview cell to refresh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{   
    jsonDict = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CountryString=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"countryName"];
    NSLog(@"country is %@", CountryString);
    [countryButton setTitle:CountryString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     countryButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    CountryTableview.hidden=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assume that its your str

```
 CountryString =@"XXXX";

UIButton *countryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; //or button type custom 
[countryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[countryButton setFrame:CGRectMake(145, 145, 100, 30)];
[countryButton setTitle: CountryString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[countryButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
countryButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
countryButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview: countryButton];   //whatever u need self.view or notesView

-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
NSLog(@"you clicked on button %@", sender.tag);
 }
```